# TFLite C++ Invoke causes seg fault on android

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow, android-ndk, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to build an android c++ app using tflite. I failed to compile the .so file on my own so I got some pre-compiled one's from the internet. I've created a dummy project to test it and it works just fine. However when I implement it on my project everything falls apart. I've checked whether the inputs are right, they are, the size is right, initialization is fine, it's almost identical with my dummy project, so what could be the issue?

Here is my code:

tflite.cpp:

```
#include "tflite.hpp"

    tflite::tflite(uint8_t *data, size_t size)
    {
        try
        {
            lib_tflite::ErrorReporter* error_reporter;

            this->m_env = lib_tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromBuffer((const char *)data, size, error_reporter);

            lib_tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;

            lib_tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*this->m_env, resolver)(&m_interpreter);

            if (m_interpreter->AllocateTensors() != kTfLiteOk)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to allocate tensor");
            }
            m_interpreter->SetNumThreads(2);

            this->m_input_node_count = m_interpreter->inputs().size();
            this->m_output_node_count = m_interpreter->outputs().size();

            for (size_t idx = 0; idx < this->m_input_node_count; ++idx)
            {
                int input = m_interpreter->inputs()[idx];
                auto height =   m_interpreter->tensor(input)->dims->data[1];
                auto width =    m_interpreter->tensor(input)->dims->data[2];
                auto channels = m_interpreter->tensor(input)->dims->data[3];

                std::vector<int> res = {(int)this->m_input_node_count, channels, width, height};
                this->m_inputDims.push_back(res);

                const TfLiteTensor* input_tensor = m_interpreter->input_tensor(idx);

                size_t element_count = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < input_tensor->dims->size; i++)
                {
                    element_count *= input_tensor->dims->data[i];
                }

                this->m_input_elem_size.push_back(element_count);
            }

            for (size_t idx = 0; idx < this->m_output_node_count; ++idx)
            {
                int output = m_interpreter->outputs()[idx];
                auto height =   m_interpreter->tensor(output)->dims->data[1];
                auto width =    m_interpreter->tensor(output)->dims->data[2];
                auto channels = m_interpreter->tensor(output)->dims->data[3];

                std::vector<int> res = {(int)this->m_output_node_count, channels, width, height};
                this->m_outputDims.push_back(res);

                const TfLiteTensor* output_tensor = m_interpreter->output_tensor(idx);

                int element_count = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < output_tensor->dims->size; i++) {
                    element_count *= output_tensor->dims->data[i];
                }
                this->m_output_elem_size.push_back(element_count);
            }

            for (size_t idx = 0; idx < this->m_input_node_count; ++idx)
            {
                this->m_input_buffer.emplace_back(this->m_input_elem_size[idx], 0
                );
            }

            for (size_t idx = 0; idx < this->m_output_node_count; ++idx)
            {
                this->m_output_buffer.emplace_back(this->m_output_elem_size[idx], 0
                );
            }
    }

    bool tflite::run(std::vector<float> &t_out_buffer,
                     std::vector<float> &t_cls_buffer,
                     std::vector<float> &t_buffer,
                     size_t region_size) noexcept
    {

        for(size_t idx = 0; idx < this->m_input_node_count; idx++)
        {
            float* data_ptr = m_interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(idx);
            memcpy(data_ptr, t_buffer.data(), this->m_input_elem_size[idx]);
        }

        // This is where it fails
        if (kTfLiteOk != this->m_interpreter->Invoke())
        {
            log_error("Failed to invoke\n");
            return false;
        }

        for(size_t idx = 0; idx < this->m_output_node_count; idx++)
        {
            float* output = this->m_interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(idx);

            this->m_output_buffer[idx] = std::vector<float> (output,
                                                             output + this->m_output_elem_size[idx]);
        }

        t_cls_buffer = this->m_output_buffer[0];
        t_out_buffer =  m_output_buffer[1];
    }

/* end_of_file */
```

tflite.hpp:

```
#ifndef TFLITE_DRIVER_HPP
#define TFLITE_DRIVER_HPP

#include <memory>

#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/optional_debug_tools.h"

    namespace lib_tflite = ::tflite;

    class tflite
    {
    public:

        tflite() = delete;

        virtual ~tflite() noexcept = default;

        tflite(tflite &&) = delete;

        tflite & operator=(tflite &&) = delete;

        tflite(const tflite &) = delete;

        tflite & operator=(tflite &) = delete;

        tflite(uint8_t *data, size_t size);

        bool run(   std::vector<float> &t_out_buffer,
                    std::vector<float> &t_cls_buffer,
                    std::vector<float> &t_buffer,
                    size_t region_size) noexcept;
    private:
        lib_tflite::ErrorReporter* error_reporter;
        
        lib_tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;

        std::unique_ptr<lib_tflite::FlatBufferModel> m_env;

        std::unique_ptr<lib_tflite::Interpreter> m_interpreter;

        std::vector<const char *> m_input_names;

        std::vector<const char *> m_output_names;

        size_t m_input_node_count;

        size_t m_output_node_count;

        std::vector<lib_tflite::Tensor> m_inputTensors;

        std::vector<lib_tflite::Tensor> m_outputTensors;

        std::vector<size_t> m_input_elem_size;

        std::vector<size_t> m_output_elem_size;

        std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_inputDims;

        std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_outputDims;

        std::vector<std::vector<float>> m_input_buffer;

        std::vector<std::vector<float>> m_output_buffer;

        std::unique_ptr<lib_tflite::MemoryAllocation> m_memory_info;

    };

#endif // TFLITE_DRIVER_HPP
/* end_of_file */
```

Note that my project runs on 2 threads, one get's the input and the other calls tflite. Like I've said the input's are indeed correct. The constructor is ran once, but the run function runs every frame.

Here is the output I get when I run it:

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.mediatek.platform"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.chipname"
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x13c6759bfc61 in tid 27936 (processing), pid 27893 (ample.nerveblox)
```

I've debugged and found out the line this error happens is where I call `this->m_interpreter->Invoke()` inside the run function.

Comment: I'm stuck at the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Error404 Well I did some stuff to fix it but it is a long run: The root of my problems were caused because I was using an ndk version above 25 so I thought I couldn't use tflite on my project. But it appears all I had to do was to download ndk 20, get a build using bazel, then just keep using ndk 25 on my project. Many of the bazel commands work after you install ndk, run ./configure and say yes to setting WORKSPACE.

Answer (score 1):

access denied error seems like there is no property for "ro.mediatek.platform" & "ro.chipname" if you run the "adb shell getprop".
So, I think, "ro.mediatek.platform" & "ro.chipname" are not a property.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in your code.

1.

```
            lib_tflite::ErrorReporter* error_reporter;

            this->m_env = lib_tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromBuffer((const char *)data, size, error_reporter);
```

`error_reporter` is uninitialized here.  You're passing an uninitialized pointer to BuildFromBuffer.  Instead, you should initialize it first, e.g.

```
error_reporter = lib_tflite::DefaultErrorReporter();
```

2. 

```
 lib_tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*this->m_env, resolver)(&m_interpreter);
```

Check the return value from this call, and/or check that `m_interpreter` is non-null afterwards.

3.

```
            m_interpreter->SetNumThreads(2);
```

This method is deprecated.  Instead, use the `SetNumThreads` method of `InterpreterBuilder`, i.e. change

```
            lib_tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*this->m_env, resolver)(&m_interpreter);
```

to

```
            lib_tflite::InterpreterBuilder builder(*this->m_env, resolver);
            builder.SetNumThreads(2);
            TfLiteStatus result = builder(&m_interpreter);
            if (status != kTfLiteOk || m_interpreter == nullptr) {
                ... report error and/or throw ...
            }
```

4. In your `tflite::run` method:

```
        for(size_t idx = 0; idx < this->m_input_node_count; idx++)
        {
            float* data_ptr = m_interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(idx);
            memcpy(data_ptr, t_buffer.data(), this->m_input_elem_size[idx]);
```

This is assuming that the Nth input is also the Nth tensor, which is not guaranteed.  Instead, use

```
        for(size_t idx = 0; idx < this->m_input_node_count; idx++)
        {
            int input = m_interpreter->inputs()[idx];
            float* data_ptr = m_interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(input);
            memcpy(data_ptr, t_buffer.data(), this->m_input_elem_size[idx]);
```

I think if you fix those issues, the problem that you were observing will most likely go away.  If not, try enabling debug information when you build your program, so that you get a proper stack trace with line numbers in the log.

Also, style-wise, it is not a good idea to name your class 'tflite', since that name is used by the TF Lite library itself, as a namespace name.